# how to increase a size of bootable section in ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, disk-usage, disk-management, vdi

I have an Ubuntu on virtual machine by VirtualBox and given space (41gb) is over, so I need to increase it's size. I modified .vdi - and now it has 9gb of space more. But how should I add this space to bootable section?

[image: view of a disk space]

Comment: What do you mean by bootable section you mean `/boot` ?

Comment: @Ravexina I mean that main part with size 47gb, where ubuntu is

Comment: I updated my answer, it should work for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we want to increase `/` size, it can be any other part of your VM as you like, it can be `/home` or whatever:

1. Get a backup of your VM files. (just in case)
2. Use `lsblk -r | grep /$` to find out witch partition is your root, if you don't know it already.

   - The output going to be like: `sda1 8:1 0 20GiB 0 part /`.
   - so mine is `sda1` => `/dev/sda1`
3. Boot your VM using a Ubuntu ISO and choose try Ubuntu to get into live sessoin.
4. Use "gparted" utility to merge your free space with boot partition which in my case was `/dev/sda1`.
5. Reboot the VM and everything should be fine.